# Can't get Spring Boot Thin Launcher examples to work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to run the `simple` app available at https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-thin-launcher under samples, and after doing a `mvn clean install` and running `java -jar simple-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, I get the following stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot locate library: C:\Users\username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher/1.0.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.9.RELEASE-exec.jar
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:113)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:90)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the latest 1.0.9.RELEASE (that's the only change I made to the source code). So, I then tried executing `java -jar simple-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --thin.library=org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-thin-launcher:1.0.9.RELEASE` and got the following stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/loader/ExecutableArchiveLauncher
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

I thought I was following the instructions available at https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-thin-launcher to run the example.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried launching without `--thin.library=org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-thin-launcher:1.0.9.RELEASE` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that first. I stated that in my post.

Comment: I noticed one thing wrong with the path, part of the path has "\" and other part of the path has "/" as separator:: 
> C:\Users\username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher/1.0.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.9.RELEASE-exec.jar

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

a workaround is to run

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-thin-launcher:1.0.9.RELEASE:jar:exec
```

once to get the missing library into your maven repo. After that, just regular `java -jar yourfile.jar` should work.

Note for others getting the same error: just replace the version of dependency in the command above with the version you're using.

This problem seems to be [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher/issues/196), so Spring people would need to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Update your Spring Boot Think version to `1.0.24.RELEASE` and follow the new documentation on their repository:

https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher